# How to assign 1 array's values to another array's values in php?

Tags: php, arrays, assign, key-value-store

I have 2 arrays:

```
$arrA = array("a", "b");
$arrB = array("1", "2");
```

How to set array a to array b and keep them different objects like making $arrayA a variable (a & b) and $arrB will be the variable of variable $a & $b? 
Like:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
```

My desired output like testing the code is like:

```
$c = $a + $b;
echo $c;
```

thanks for the help

Comment: `echo $c;` ... what do you expect to see here?  It's not clear from your question (at least, it's not clear to me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `extract` & `array_combine`

```
$arrA = array("a", "b");
$arrB = array("1", "2");

extract(array_combine($arrA, $arrB));
echo $a + $b ;
```

Output

> 3

Comment: is it deafault without printing it? like $a the default value is 1? LIKE: $a = 1; without the used of echo?

Comment: `extract` would automatically create the variable even if you don't pint it

Comment: whats the difference putting a true ex: extract(array_combine($arr1, $arr2), TRUE);

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
<?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```

Comment: how im gonna print the variable something like when I used the array_combine.

Comment: Use [`extract()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) if you want to turn each array key into its own variable. In my example it would be `extract($c)`